# Create unique object from some arrays JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Help solve the problem.

I have an object like this

```
const a = {
  '123': ['asd', 'qwe', 'zxc'],
  '456': ['iop', 'jkl', 'bnm']
}
```

It is necessary to convert it to this form

```
const b = [
  '123_asd__456_iop',
  '123_asd__456_jkl',
  '123_asd__456_bnm',
  '...',
  '123_zxc__456_jkl',
  '123_zxc__456_bnm'
]
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: From next time please show what you have tried. this platform is for help but please try and show what you have done to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the object to an array of `[key, values]` entries using `Object.entries()`, and reduce the entries a new array. Map the current array of `values`, and create a string for each `val` with the current `key`.

If the accumulator (`acc`) is empty, return the create an array of strings. If the `acc` is not empty, iterate it with `Array.flatMap()`, map the array of values of the current entry (`arr`), and combine the strings.

```js
const obj = {
  '123': ['asd', 'qwe', 'zxc'],
  '456': ['iop', 'jkl', 'bnm']
}

const entryToString = key => val => `${key}_${val}`

const result = Object.entries(obj)
  .reduce((acc, [key, values]) => {
    const createString = entryToString(key)
  
    return acc.length ?
      acc.flatMap(s1 => values.map(s2 => `${s1}__${createString(s2)}`))
      :
      values.map(createString)
  }, [])
  
console.log(result)
```